# How to locate/print abort trap: 6 error in large C++ code

Tags: c++, clang, runtime-error

I have a fairly large C++ code (multiple hpp and cpp files). It compiles properly. However, when I run, I get this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string Abort trap: 6
```

I understand that this error indicates an out of range error on a string, but how do I know where this error occurs? Is there a way to print out the file and line number that is throwing this error? I'm not worried about solving the issue yet, just helping find the offending line.

Comment: By running the code in a debugger. You can then set breakpoints on areas that use string indexing to narrow down where the problem happens to help isolate that code, and then step through the code to figure out what's causing the exception. First, run the app in the debugger, and when the exception is thrown, use the callstack to find the last line in your own code that executed. That's the place to start looking closely.

Comment: Try this stacktrace library.  It may not catch faults, but it should catch C++ exceptions https://github.com/certik/stacktrace

Comment: On linux you can also simply do `catchsegv ./myApp` instead of `./myApp` to get a call stack on crashes.

Comment: If you run your code under the debugger, you should be abler to put a breakpoint on `abort`.  Then, when the program crashes, you should be able to get a backtrace which will identify the offending line of code.

Comment: @PaulSanders Are there debuggers out there that don't have that breakpoint implicitly set by default?

Comment: You might have some luck putting `try{...}catch{...}` frameworks around function calls. You only need to catch the one specific exception, and you can log the line number at that point. Starting with the creation of the strings in question, some intelligent placement of the `catch`es will allow you to track down the culprit in a few iterations.

Comment: Have you tried gdb?

Comment: @frank IDK, my code never aborts :)

Comment: Compile with debug info (add `-g3` option) and run under gdb and execute `catch throw std::out_of_range` in the debugger prompt before actually running the program. Then it will stop at the point when exception is thrown and you will be able to look at stacktrace with `bt`.